# Profiling: how to find out which object a method is attached to?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling

I have inherited a JavaScript application and I am trying to understand how it works using profiling in Chrome.

Chrome gives me the sequence of methods that are executed, but I only see the method name. How can I find out which object a given method is attached to?

Comment: There should be a link to the appropriate source code line where the function is called in the "Function" column of the "Collect JavaScript CPU" report.

Comment: @adamb right, but the line just says `this.theMethod=...`. I am trying to find `this`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the call stack in Chrome dev tools for a specific method, you need to set a break point in the "Sources" panel.

Here's the entire process:

1. **Run** "Collect JavaScript CPU" Report
2. In the functions column, click the **right-hand link** (of the function in question) to jump to the appropriate source code line
3. Set a **break point** on that line
4. **Re-run** the script (usually via page refresh)
5. If break point is hit, call stack will be presented on the right-side column of the "Sources" panel

Comment: thx. I am still confused because the code uses a constructor pattern and I am always sent back to the constructor Function, not the object. I'll keep trying.